# fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, caffe, ubuntu-18.04

I have been trying to build the code for single shot object detector SSD [SSD ob github](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) on Ubuntu 18.04
I checked out the code and tried to installed the dependencies based on what is suggested in the link ([Ubuntu installation](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html))

which included these:

```
sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libopencv-dev libhdf5-serial-dev protobuf-compiler

sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends libboost-all-dev
```

When I am trying to follow the instructions to build the code I am getting this error:

```
user:~/project/SSD/caffe$ make -j8
CXX src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp
CXX src/caffe/syncedmem.cpp
CXX src/caffe/parallel.cpp
CXX src/caffe/internal_thread.cpp
CXX src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/net.cpp
CXX src/caffe/data_reader.cpp
src/caffe/net.cpp:8:10: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
 #include "hdf5.h"
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:575: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/net.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/net.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I thought by installing libhdf5-serial-dev hdf5 dependency is done but it seems that for some reason it is not enough?

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: I tried the solution by installing and adding the CPATH but it did not work and still complaining about hdf5.h not found